# I have a formArray and in that formArray I have just formControls, not formGroup, how can I loop trough that controls in html?

Tags: angular

When I try to loop trough controls of formArray I get an error that formControlName must be in a formGroup, but I don't have a formGroup in formArray. The code in html looks like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3eIF.png)

and in .ts it is like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7pSK.png)

How can I solve this problem when I don't have a formGroup but Angular wants to provide formGroup

Comment: You need to add code here or try to reproduce it on stackblitz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to use `answers()` method, which casts to FormArray and avoids that (false) error.

```html
*ngFor="let answer of answers().controls"
```